# How do I format a MAC address to be separated by colons?

Tags: formatting, microsoft-excel-2013, text-formatting

In Excel 2013, I'd like to take the following MAC addresses and create a custom format mask to put colons separating every two characters.

```
80BE05AF20E0
C0F2FB0326E2
80BE05C52449
```

I've tried variations of `@, ?, 0` as format mask values, but Excel is having a difficult time processing the values. What I want to see displayed is:

```
80:BE:05:AF:20:E0
C0:F2:FB:03:26:E2
80:BE:05:C5:24:49
```

Comment: No, you can't do this with a format mask. You'll need a formula. Or VBA.

Comment: If you need a second opinion, no you cannot do this with a format mask. Format masks work great with numbers, but don't work with text.